# How to reset a input/select field on the UI from controller without loading the whole form

Tags: angularjs

I have two fields on the form, changing one field value should reset other field value based on conditions. How can i do that.

```
    <select id="code"
        name="code"
        data-ng-model="vm.formData.code"
        data-ng-options="code.id+ ' - ' + code.description for codein vm.codes track by code.id"
        data-ng-change="vm.updateTypeField(vm.formData.code, vm.formData.type)"
        required>
    </select>


   <select id="type"
       name="type"
       data-ng-model="vm.formData.type"
       data-ng-options="type.id+ ' - ' + type.description for codein vm.types track by type.id"
       data-ng-change="vm.updateCodeField(vm.formData.code, vm.formData.type)"
       required>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i well understood your question, [this example](https://codepen.io/FederalCircle/pen/geqgrY) may solve the problem. If not, please consider give more details.

Basicaly, `updateTypeField()` and `updateCodeField()` have access to `formData`, so the bellow function would do what you want:

```
function updateTypeField() {
  if (vm.formData.code.id == 2) {
     vm.formData.type = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was updating vm.code instead of vm.formData.code in my controller.